# ssh - user xyz does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

when connection via ssh to a server I get the following message:

```
-ssh-bash: User #1003 does not exit in /etc/passwd.
```

It used to work and newly I made an update to the ssl libraries on my ubuntu.
How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you invoke `ssh`? You can specify a user by doing this: `ssh FinbarMcFoo@securehost.com`. This user must of course exist on securehost.com ...

Comment: Is it possible you've changed user on the machine you're logging in from?  If so, then SSH would be trying to log you in as the wrong user (if not explicitly using the username).